# how to measure filter processing time in Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

let's say I have pipeline like this:
`videotestsrc -> x264enc -> filesink`

I want to measure **h264 encoding time** of each frame.
But since I might change the codec in the future, I don't want it to be x264enc specific.
(It could be nvenc, vaapi..etc)

I saw few people achieved this by creating custom filter, such as:
https://github.com/mpekar/gstreamer_timestamp_marking

But considering Gstreamer is optimized for real-time application, I think there might be better way of doing this.
Is there any built-in feature for measuring duration of each filters?

Comment: Encoders often queue up multiple frames for analyzing before actually encoding. So you cannot easily measure here..

Comment: @FlorianZwoch thank you for your comment. you are right. But I noticed when encoding using baseline profiles with zero latency tune & ultrafast preset which only contains I & P frames, encoder usually outputs the data right after the frame.
I'm not sure if it can be done with Gstreamer, But if you see Nvidia Video Codec SDK samples, they measure the encoding latency just by using timedelta between before & after encoding function call.

Comment: In corner cases you can. Still to be an encoder efficient it likes to do lookahead for a good rate distortion. Anyway - you can still do it. Check out `GstPadProbe`. You can set callbacks when buffers pass though pads this way. There you can do measurements if you want.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Well since trade-offs between efficiency and performance is inevitable, my encoder won't do any lookahead. anyway, `GstPadProbe` is really the thing I was looking for. Thank you again.